My new staging slot cannot connect to a github workflow
I just upgraded my azure web application so that I can have additional deployment slots. I want to be able to push updates from my github to the azure staging slot of my web app so that i can confirm my changes are functioning and loaded before "swapping" it to the my production slot where my domain is active.
I can setup continuous deployment on my production slot but when i try to set it up under my staging slot it always gives me errors telling me my resource is not found in github actions. Does anyone have feedback or experience on this?

can you share your yml file?


I am using Publish profile for authentication to azure web app.

To deploy in different slot from GitHub follow these steps:

Create new slot and Open it.



Download the publish profile of the new slot



Mention your slot name in slot-name in the yml file .
Create a new secret in the GitHub and add your publish profile value in the secret. Use this secret in the workflow file.


Below given .yml file worked for me.
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - webapp19june

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'staging'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'webapp19june'
          slot-name: 'staging'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SLOT }}

OUTPUT:


